# Is it possible to put a link inside a tooltip using Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, tooltip

Is it possible to add a link inside a tool tip using Prime Faces

i cant find a way to add a link inside the tool tip. I tried to add hideDelay but it doesn't seems to work, not sure why.

This is what i got :

```
    <h:column id="opf1007_column_col08" 
                                rendered="#{pc_Opf1007.w_op_forecast.colbll08 ne null}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridHeaderText"
                                        value="#{pc_Opf1007.w_op_forecast.colbll08}"
                                        id="opf1007_gridheader_col08" 
                                        style="text-align:right;width:120px">
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </f:facet>

                                <p:inputText styleClass="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.inputClass}"
                                    id="opf1007_gridinput_col08"
                                    value="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.col08}"
                                    style="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.style}color: #{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.col08 lt 0 ? 'red' : 'blue'};width:100px;text-align:right" 
                                    readonly="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.total_row}">
                                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="0" minFractionDigits="0"/>
                                </p:inputText>

                                <p:commandButton ajax="false" type="submit" 
                                    styleClass="iconCommandButton"
                                    id="opf1007_command_col08" icon="ui-icon-search"
                                    action="#{pc_Opf1007.doOpf1007_command_listAction}" 
                                    style="width:14px;height:14px" 
                                    rendered="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.showIcon}">
                                    <f:param name="clicked_groupid"
                                        value="#{varlistOfGridForecasts_Single.groupid}"></f:param>
                                    <f:param name="clicked_col_frdate"
                                        value="#{pc_Opf1007.w_op_forecast.col08_frdate}"></f:param> 
                                    <f:param name="clicked_col_todate"
                                        value="#{pc_Opf1007.w_op_forecast.col08_todate}"></f:param> 
                                </p:commandButton>

                                <p:tooltip for="opf1007_command_col08" value="#{msg.opf1007_tooltip_click}" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" hideDelay="500"
                                    style="width:270px"/>
                            </h:column>
```

The Result: I got my tooltip to hover over my command button, but the there is no delay in the hiding.

Comment: Did you try? Result? Then you have your answer

Comment: Ah, the tooltip appears but, doesn't show the link. @Kukeltje